# allMatch, anyMatch on lists without creating streams

Tags: java, java-8

It bothers me (for performance reasons) that I can't call allMatch, anyMatch on lists without first creating streams. So I started creating utility methods like this:

```
public static <T> boolean anyMatch(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    for (T element : list) {
        if (predicate.test(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there no easier way?

**EDIT** I'm not just worried about the cost of a single object. If you look at the source of Stream.anyMatch, you can see that a lot of things happen which are not necessary in this simple case.

Comment: Well, several other libraries from the pre-Java8 days have solved these kinds of problems.

Comment: What performance issues occur when you attempt to use a `Stream`?

Comment: @JacobG. Probably nothing serious, but it still bothers me. Stream obviously does a lot of things that are not needed in such a simple case.

Comment: So you are not seeing the `Iterator` created by the loop and feel better? Then, there is no easier solution to you goal.

Comment: @Holger Good point about the iterator, although I'm pretty sure that the JVM does not actually create an Iterator object when it is clear that the same result can be achieved without it. (in principle the stream creation could also be optimized away, but I doubt that they did it - if they cared about this, they could have simply add these methods to List)

Comment: You are making unfounded wild guesses. There is no reason why an `Iterator` could be better optimized than a `Stream`, both are ordinary, small Java objects. The design decisions about the Stream API have been discussed at other places. You should measure instead of wasting your time with the creation of redundant methods.

Comment: @Holger as I explained in the other comment, the Stream might be a single object, but is is obviously optimized for more complicated usage scenarios and does a lot of things which are not necessary in such a simple case. Please direct me to any discussions regarding the inclusion of anyMatch to List - I searched, but I didn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

Your new method seems a good idea. Although it would be better if you use [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) instead of a utility method just to maintain a good Object Oriented Design.

```
public class StreamList<T> {
 List<T> list;
 public StreamList(List list) {
  this.list = list;
 }
 public boolean anyMatch(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    for (T element : list) {
        if (predicate.test(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, +1! You obviously meant do remove the "static" in this case

Comment: The constructor's parameter should be of type `List<T>`, and you're defining `T` again for some reason for `StreamList#anyMatch`.

Comment: @Holger No, I'm not just worried about the cost of a single object. If you look at the source of Stream.anyMatch, you can see that a lot of things happen which are not necessary in this simple case